# Pass value from controller to factory to choose between objects

Tags: angularjs, factory

I have a quiz-application built in AngularJS in which I would like to choose between two objects, dependent on which quiz you choose in the view. When a quiz is selected in the view a function is executed. In this process I am sending a variable to the dataservice.js file that contain the objects and in here i have an if statement that chooses the right object depending in the input from the controller. 
How do i use the quiz-variable outside of the changeState function? I want to use it to choose between the two quiz objects.

//controller

```
    function activateQuiz(){

        quizMetrics.changeState("quiz", true);
        DataService.startQuiz("quiz_1");
        //test("hund");

    }   

    function activateQuiz_2(){

        quizMetrics.changeState("quiz", true);
        DataService.startQuiz("quiz_2");
        //test("kat");

    }
```

//Factory

(function(){

```
/*
 * Declaring a factory service as part of the existing turtleFacts Module.
 */
angular
    .module("turtleFacts")
    .factory("DataService", DataService);
/*
 * Actual definition of the function used for this factory
 */
function DataService(){
    /*
     * dataObj is used to simulate getting the data from a backend server
     * The object will hold data which will then be returned to the other
     * factory declared in js/factory/quiz.js which has this factory
     * as a dependency
     */

    var dataObj = {
        startQuiz: startQuiz,
        quizQuestions: quizQuestions,
        correctAnswers: correctAnswers
    };

    var dataObj_2 = {
        startQuiz: startQuiz,
        quizQuestions: quizQuestions_2,
        correctAnswers: correctAnswers_2
    };


            var quiz;
            function startQuiz(metric, state){
            if(metric === "quiz_1"){
                quiz = "quiz1"
            }else if(metric === "quiz_2"){
                quiz = "quiz2"
            }else{
                return false;
            }   
            console.log(quiz)

        } 

            if (quiz = "quiz1") { // here i want to use the the quiz variable from the changeState function. 
            return dataObj;
                } else if (quiz = "quiz2") {
            return dataObj_2;
            }  

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could have something like this:

```
 /*
 * Declaring a factory service as part of the existing turtleFacts Module.
 */
angular
    .module("turtleFacts")
    .factory("DataService", DataService);
/*
 * Actual definition of the function used for this factory
 */
function DataService(){
    /*
     * dataObj is used to simulate getting the data from a backend server
     * The object will hold data which will then be returned to the other
     * factory declared in js/factory/quiz.js which has this factory
     * as a dependency
     */

    var dataObj = {
        changeState: changeState,
        quizQuestions: quizQuestions,
        correctAnswers: correctAnswers
    };

    var dataObj_2 = {
        changeState: changeState,
        quizQuestions: quizQuestions_2,
        correctAnswers: correctAnswers_2
    };

    var quiz;

    function changeState(metric, state){
        if(metric === "quiz_1"){
            quiz = "quiz1"
        }else if(metric === "quiz_2"){
            quiz = "quiz2"
        }else{
            return false;
        }   
        console.log(quiz);

        if (quiz == "quiz1") { // here i want to use the the quiz variable from the changeState function. 
            return dataObj;
        } else if (quiz == "quiz2") {
            return dataObj_2;
        }  
    } 
}
```

And from your controller, you can get the data as:

```
$scope.quiz = DataService. changeState(metric, state);
```

Comment: Hi Pratek Thanks for the answer. I could not get it to work though. I am trying to pass a value with rootscope until i can make it work with a service.

Comment: What do you mean by *could not get it work*? Is there an error? Do you get a different response? Could you please elaborate the issue?

Comment: Hi Prerak. I was able to pass in a value from the controller to the changestate function that i have placed within the Dataservice function in the factory. The quiz variable is changing depending on which quiz that is selected on the html page, so this is working. but i cannot seem to take in the quiz variable in the condition to choose either quiz1 or quiz2. What am i doing wrong here. Thank You for your help. /Daniel

Comment: It would be better if you could update your question with the latest code sample.

Comment: var quiz;
          function changeState(metric, state){
                if(metric === "quiz_1"){
     quiz = "quiz1"
                }else if(metric === "quiz_2"){
     quiz = "quiz2"
                }else{
                    return false;
                } 
      console.log(quiz)
            } 
   
       
    if (quiz = "quiz1") { // here i want to use the the quiz variable from the changeState function. 
    return dataObj;
     } else if (quiz = "quiz2") {
    return dataObj_2;
    }

Comment: `=` is an assignment operator and `==` is a comparison operator. So you need to use `==` in your condition to match the values. E.g `if(quiz == "quiz1")`

Comment: Update the question with your latest code of the factory and controller, so I could have a look. Don't paste it in comments as it is unreadable.

Comment: How come i cannot console.log(quiz)/access quiz outside the changeState function?

Comment: Check my updated answer. You cannot directly do some conditioning in a factory. You need to do that inside a function. Also your `if` condition was wrong. It should be `==` but you were using `=`.

Comment: Thanks for your response, i will implement it.

Comment: Hi Pratek. In the code above i have added the functions that is being fired from the controller and how they come into the factory. I cannot see how i can go about choosing between object1 and object2 without creating logic indside the factory. I can create conditions inside the controller, but it does not get me any further when i want to return the objects. Do you have any suggestions. Thank you /D